# configure: error: Cannot find private header tclInt.h in /home/dave/src/tcl-builds/raw/tcl8.4.1

Tags: tcl, itcl

I am trying to build open source tcl code.
I am hitting error below:

```
configure: error: Cannot find private header tclInt.h in /home/dave/src/tcl-builds/raw/tcl8.4.1
```

from the configure script I am not seeing the path mentioned above in error message..i am not sure from where this path is coming. 
Any help?

FYI, I Tried this WAR : https://sourceforge.net/p/expect/bugs/30/ which did not help.

Comment: What platform are you building on? You might need to get a copy of the Tcl source code to build; it depends on whether there are development packages that you can use that include the Tcl private headers.

Comment: I am working on aarch64 platform. Linux krfarm012 4.5.0-15.4.2.el7.aarch64 #1 SMP Wed Mar 22 15:58:27 EDT 2017 aarch64 aarch64 aarch64 GNU/Linux

Comment: If it is open source, then provide a complete set of reproducible steps: sources? how obtained? exact configure line etc.

Comment: Also: what is the content of directory `/home/dave/src/tcl-builds/raw/tcl8.4.1`